# Mapping Tables Sorting Conflicts

Tags: c#

I have two tables, one is for the user to select and the other one is from another system. The system table is mapped to the user input table.

Orderables Table:

```
+-----+-------------------------------+
| Key |           Orderable           |
+-----+-------------------------------+
|  88 | XRAY Spine Cervical           |
|  91 | XRAY Spine Lumbar             |
|  95 | XRAY Spine Thoracic           |
+-----+-------------------------------+
```

Karisma(System) Table:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|        KarismaName        | KarismaCode | OrderableKeys |
+---------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| Spine Cervical            | 310XR       | 88            |
| Spine Cervical + Lumbar   | 302XR       | 88|91         |
| Spine Cervical + Thoracic | 301XR       | 88|95         |
| Spine Lumbosacral         | 330XR       | 91            |
| Spine Thoracic            | 320XR       | 95            |
| Spine Thoracic + Lumbar   | 303XR       | 95|91         |
+---------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I have these classes:

```
public class orderable
    {
        public int Key { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Modality { set; get; }
        public orderable()
        {
            Key = 0;
            Name = string.Empty;
        }
    }
public class Exam
    {
        public string KarismaName { set; get; }
        public string KarismaCode { set; get; }
        public string OrderableKeys { set; get; }
        public int Key { set; get; }
        public List<orderable> Orderables { set; get; }
        public Exam()
        {
            KarismaCode = string.Empty;
            KarismaName = string.Empty;
            Key = 0;
            Orderables = new List<orderable>();
            OrderableKeys = string.Empty;
        }
    }
public class ConflictExams
    {
        public List<Exam> ExamList { set; get; }
        public List<int> OrderablesList { set; get; }
    }
public class ConflictOptions
    {
        public List<Options> OptionsList { set; get; }
    }
    public class Options
    {
        public List<Exam> ExamsList {set; get;}
    }
```

This is my code to get all conflicting exams, i.e. Orderables that appear in more than one combination exams:

```
List<ConflictExams> conflictList = new List<ConflictExams>();
            foreach (var i in duplicateKeys)
            {
                List<Exam> examsList = new List<Exam>();
                List<int> orderableList = new List<int>();
                foreach (var ex in comboExamsList)
                {
                    var split = ex.OrderableKeys.Split('|');
                    foreach (var s in split)
                    {
                        if(int.Parse(s) == i)
                        {
                            examsList.Add(ex);
                            orderableList.Add(i);
                        }
                    }                        
                }
                ConflictExams ce = new ConflictExams();
                ce.ExamList = examsList;         
                ce.OrderablesList = orderableList;
                conflictList.Add(ce);
            }
```

The results of my code is conflictList =

```
conflictList[0].ExamList[0] = Spine Cervical + Lumbar
conflictList[0].ExamList[1] = Spine Cervical + Thoracic
conflictList[1].ExamList[0] = Spine Cervical + Lumbar
conflictList[1].ExamList[1] = Spine Thoracic + Lumbar
conflictList[2].ExamList[0] = Spine Cervical + Thoracic
conflictList[2].ExamList[1] = Spine Thoracic + Lumbar
```

I don't know how to get from there to a list of options so that the user chooses which they want to select, this is the ultimate goal:

```
conflictOptionsList[0].Options[0].ExamsList[0] = Spine Cervical + Lumbar
conflictOptionsList[0].Options[0].ExamsList[1] = Spine Thoracic
conflictOptionsList[0].Options[1].ExamsList[0] = Spine Cervical + Thoracic
conflictOptionsList[0].Options[1].ExamsList[1] = Spine Lumbar
conflictOptionsList[0].Options[2].ExamsList[0] = Spine Thoracic + Lumbar
conflictOptionsList[0].Options[2].ExamsList[1] = Spine Cervical
```

I hope that makes a lot more sense and I thank you all for looking and comments.